# Android SQLite update row not working and no errors shown

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, sqlite

I've bee trying to update a row trough SQLite in android trough a fragment  but it does not update the tables and I do not get any errors either. Here is my code .. maybe I am missing something. Thank you

### MySQLiteHelper class

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String MYDATABASE = "myDataBase";
    public static final String MYTABLE = "myTable";
    public static final String USERNAME = "myUser";
    public static final String PASSWORD = "myPass";
    public static final String EMAIL = "myEmail";
    public static final int VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";


    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, MYDATABASE, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MYTABLE + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + USERNAME + " TEXT," + PASSWORD + " TEXT,"
                + EMAIL + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //any upgrade can update the version and if newV > oldV then upgrade will be exected
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + MYTABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public Integer deleteData(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(MYTABLE, "_id = ?", new String[] {id});
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String user, String pass, String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(USERNAME, user);
        cv.put(PASSWORD, pass);
        cv.put(EMAIL, email);
        db.update(MYTABLE, cv, "_id = ?", new String[] {id});
        return true;
    }


}
```

### Main Activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    EditText etUser, etPass, etEmail;
    Button btSave, btShow;
    MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    ListView lvRecords;
    ArrayList<String> userDataList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started");

        etUser = findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        btSave = findViewById(R.id.btSave);
        btShow = findViewById(R.id.btShow);
        lvRecords = findViewById(R.id.lvRecords);

        userDataList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        sqLiteDatabase = mySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //write and read

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userDataList);
        lvRecords.setAdapter(adapter);
        showList();

        lvRecords.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String selectedData = userDataList.get(position);
                String rowId = selectedData.substring(0,1);
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemLongClick: *******id " + rowId);
                Integer deleteRow = mySQLiteHelper.deleteData(rowId);
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position: " + rowId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                return false;
            }
        });

        lvRecords.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                UpdateFragment updateFragment = new UpdateFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, updateFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

                String selectedData = userDataList.get(position);
                String[] userData = selectedData.split("\\s+");
                String userId = userData[0];
                String userName = userData[1];
                String userPass = userData[2];
                String userEmail = userData[3];

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("position", position);
                b.putString("id", userId);
                b.putString("user", userName);
                b.putString("pass", userPass);
                b.putString("email", userEmail);
                updateFragment.setArguments(b);


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        btShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showList();
            }

        });

        btSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //content values to put the data in the database
                //same order as table creation fields order
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


                String user = etUser.getText().toString();
                String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
                String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

                contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.USERNAME, user);
                contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD, pass);
                contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.EMAIL, email);
                sqLiteDatabase.insert(mySQLiteHelper.MYTABLE, null, contentValues);

                hideKeyboard();

                showList();

                etUser.setText("");
                etPass.setText("");
                etEmail.setText("");
            }
        });


    }



    public void hideKeyboard() {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
                Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
    }

    private void showList() {
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + mySQLiteHelper.MYTABLE, null);

            cursor.moveToFirst();
            userDataList.clear();


            //to read the first iteration use a do while
            do {
                if(cursor != null) {

                    int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID));
                    String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.USERNAME));
                    String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD));
                    String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.EMAIL));

                    userDataList.add(id + " " + user + " " + pass + " " + email);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ******rows: " + mySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID + ":" + id + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass + " email: " + email);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "id: " + id + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass + " email: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());


    }



}
```

### UpdateFragment.class

```
public class UpdateFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "UpdateFragment";

    Button btUpdate, btClose;
    EditText etUser, etPass, etEmail;
    Fragment me = this;
    MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    String userId, username, password, email;
    int position, e;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_update, container, false);

        etUser = v.findViewById(R.id.etUserFrag);
        etPass = v.findViewById(R.id.etPassFrag);
        etEmail = v.findViewById(R.id.etEmailFrag);
        btUpdate = v.findViewById(R.id.btUpdateFrag);
        btClose = v.findViewById(R.id.btCloseFrag);

        Bundle b = getArguments();
        position = b.getInt("position");
        position = position -1;
        userId =  b.getString("id");
        e = Integer.parseInt(userId);
        //e = e - 1;
        //userId = userId -1 ;
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: **********userID: " + userId);
        username = b.getString("user");
        password = b.getString("pass");
        email = b.getString("email");

        etUser.setText(username);
        etPass.setText(password);
        etEmail.setText(email);

        mySQLiteHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(getContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = mySQLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase(); //write and read

        btClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                closeFragment();
            }
        });

        btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {//
                boolean isUpdate = mySQLiteHelper.updateData(userId, username, password, email);
                if(isUpdate==true)
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Data Update",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Data not Updated",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
        });








        return v;
    }

    private void closeFragment() {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(me).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue 1 null Cursor

**NEVER** consider that an empty cursor is null.

SQLiteDatabase methods that return a Cursor will return a valid Cursor not null. The Cursor, if empty, will have a count of 0 (i.e. `cursor.getCount() == 0`).

So if you simply do (as per in your **showlist** method)

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (cursor == null) {
        do you stuff here
    }
```

The you'd get an index error if the Cursor was empty. You should instead check the result of the `cursor.moveToFirst()`, it will be false if there are now rows extracted. However it's easier to use a **while** loop (see code below).

### Issue 1-2 Close Cursors

***You should also close a Cursor when done with it.***

The corrected/better **showList** method :-

```
private void showList() {
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + mySQLiteHelper.MYTABLE, null);

    userDataList.clear();
    //<<<<<<<<<< simpler while loop >>>>>>>>>>
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID));
        String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.USERNAME));
        String pass = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD));
        String email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(mySQLiteHelper.EMAIL));

        userDataList.add(id + " " + user + " " + pass + " " + email);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: ******rows: " + mySQLiteHelper.KEY_ID + ":" + id + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass + " email: " + email);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "id: " + id + " user: " + user + " pass: " + pass + " email: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

## Issue 2 - Save when no data has been input.

If you click the Save button and no data has been input into a field, then a new row will be added. This will result, if the item is clicked in the ListView, in a crash due to index errors in the arrays as the **split** will not extract 4 items (only the **id** is guaranteed).

The following would correct this (look at commenets):-

```
    btSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //<<<<<<<<<< Start of Extra Code >>>>>>>>>>
            if (
                    etUser.getText().toString().length() < 1 ||
                            etEmail.getText().toString().length() < 1 ||
                            etPass.getText().toString().length() < 1
                    ) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"WHOA ENTER DATA IN ALL FIELDS!!!!!!!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            //<<<<<<<<<< End of Extra Code >>>>>>>>>>
            //content values to put the data in the database
            //same order as table creation fields order
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            String user = etUser.getText().toString();
            String pass = etPass.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.USERNAME, user);
            contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD, pass);
            contentValues.put(mySQLiteHelper.EMAIL, email);
            sqLiteDatabase.insert(mySQLiteHelper.MYTABLE, null, contentValues);
            hideKeyboard();
            showList();
            etUser.setText("");
            etPass.setText("");
            etEmail.setText("");
        }
    });
```

## Issue 3 - updateData method always returns true

The SQliteDatabase **update** method returns the number of affected rows, so if no row is updated (changing a row to the same values counts as an update) 0 will be returned. You **updateData** method doesn't check the result so always returns true.

Perhaps change it to be  :-

```
public boolean updateData(String id, String user, String pass, String email) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(USERNAME, user);
    cv.put(PASSWORD, pass);
    cv.put(EMAIL, email);
    if (db.update(MYTABLE, cv, "_id = ?", new String[] {id}) > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To provide more accurate feedback (and to highlight your main issue) the following method could be added to get the data according to an id :-

```
public Cursor getDataById(String id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = KEY_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    return db.query(MYTABLE,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
}
```

- Note use of this is incorporated in the **main issue** below.

## The Main Issue

The main issue, that is resulting in no updates, is because you are passing the old values to the update rather than the values as per the EditTexts.

The following code changes the **UPDATE Button**'s **onClickListener** to resolve this issue and also provides better feedback via the Toast's that are issued :-

```
    btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//
            //boolean isUpdate = mySQLiteHelper.updateData(userId, username, password, email);
            boolean isUpdate = mySQLiteHelper.updateData(
                    userId,
                    etUser.getText().toString(),
                    etPass.getText().toString(),
                    etEmail.getText().toString()
            );
            Cursor csr = mySQLiteHelper.getDataById(userId);
            String newUser = "not found";
            String newEmail = "not found";
            String newPass = "not found";
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                newUser = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.USERNAME));
                newEmail = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.EMAIL));
                newPass = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD));
            }
            csr.close();
            if(isUpdate==true)
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Data Updated - User now " + newUser +
                                " Email now " + newEmail +
                                " Password now " + newPass,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Data not Updated - User is " + newUser +
                                " Email is " + newEmail +
                                " Password is " + newPass,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
        }
    });

    btUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //boolean isUpdate = mySQLiteHelper.updateData(userId, username, password, email); //<<<<<<<<<< Commented out (old)
            //<<<<<<<<<< NEW (gets values from the edit texts)
            boolean isUpdate = mySQLiteHelper.updateData(
                    userId,
                    etUser.getText().toString(),
                    etPass.getText().toString(),
                    etEmail.getText().toString()
            );
            //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED to get current stored data for Toast
            Cursor csr = mySQLiteHelper.getDataById(userId);
            String newUser = "not found";
            String newEmail = "not found";
            String newPass = "not found";
            if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
                newUser = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.USERNAME));
                newEmail = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.EMAIL));
                newPass = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.PASSWORD));
            }
            csr.close();
            //<<<<<<<<< CHANGES so more info is provided by Toasts
            if(isUpdate==true)
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                        "Data Updated - User now " + newUser +
                                " Email now " + newEmail +
                                " Password now " + newPass,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Data not Updated - User is " + newUser +
                                " Email is " + newEmail +
                                " Password is " + newPass,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: wow, this is a great answer and a lot to go on! Thank you very much ! I am new to SQLite so this is of great help.